# bootstrap modal body background: none

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

how to remove background color of bootstrap modal body. I tried to use

```
.modal-body{
  background: none !important;
}
```

it is not working.

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1708/)

Comment: The `.modal` has the white background and `.modal-backdrop` has the grey one. Style the one you need to change.

Comment: `modal-content`. try it out

Comment: `none` is also the same as white and empty. :p

Comment: Use ".modal-backdrop
{
  opacity:0 !important;
}"

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1709/)

```
.modal{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the modal as a full-view,
This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjeyqg4q/1/) is for you.

```
.modal{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are background-color at `.modal-backdrop` instead of `.modal-body`. So, apply this:

```
.modal-backdrop { background: none; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1710/)